# Too much whitespace after verbatim command

Tags: latex

If I put the following LaTeX code:

```
\begin{singlespace}
\begin{verbatim}
```

There is too much whitespace before the text inside those tags appear. It looks like there are two line breaks. Is there a way to reduce this whitespace?

Comment: Can you provide a self-contained minimal example that shows the problem?

Answer (score 5):

Many environments put some default surrounding space around their contents.  The correct way is most likely to find out how the variable that determines this space is called and modify it (temporarily, or for the whole file).  For a quick and dirty fix, however, you can just use some negative vspace:

```
Lorem ipsum...

\vspace{-1ex}

\begin{strangedays}
% ...
```

Comment: The best way I could find!

Answer (score 1):

A look into the LaTeX kernel ([`latex.ltx`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/unpacked/latex.ltx)) shows the definition

```
\def\@verbatim{\trivlist \item\relax
  \if@minipage\else\vskip\parskip\fi
  [...]
```

In other words, it adds a `\parskip` at the start unless verbatim is executed in "`minipage` mode".

So try using

```
\begin{quote}
\begin{verbatim}
...
\end{verbatim}
\end{quote}
```

This way, verbatim is executed in `minipage` mode and will not add a `\parskip` at the start.

Normally, you want to add some indentation when quoting source code or the like with `verbatim`, so using `quote` is what you want to do anyway.